# Python check if force closed

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a python file 'program.py' running in a terminal window. I need that program to log something like say 'force closed' to a file when the window in which it was running was terminated manually. I've read that the program sends a status code of -1 for unsuccessful execution, but how do I read and do something based on that?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the signal module http://pymotw.com/2/signal/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. A process can't read it's own exit code. That would not make much sense. But in order to force process shutdown the OS has to send a signal to that process. As long as it is not SIGKILL and/or SIGSTOP then you can intercept it via [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) library. SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be blocked, e.g. if someone does `kill -9` then there's nothing you can do.

To use signal library:

```
import signal
import sys

def handler(signum, frame):
    # do the cleaning if necessary

    # log your data here
    with open('log.log', 'a') as fo:
        fo.write('Force quit on %s.\n' % signum)

    # force quit
    sys.exit(1)  # only 0 means "ok"

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
```

When terminal closes it sends SIGHUP to a process.

SIGINT is used for CTRL-C interruption.

SIGTERM is similar to SIGKILL. The difference is that the process can catch it. It's a "graceful kill".

**IMPORTANT:** This is true for all POSIX systems. I don't know much about other OS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, does this kill include removing the process from the task manager(windows)?

Comment: @T90 My apologies, I assumed that we are talking about POSIX systems (Linux). I hope it is somewhat similar under Windows but I'm not really sure. But you can test it and let me know. :)

Comment: sorry for the late response, but that method works only Linux

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that, if the process is killed the program is over, he can't do additional things before disappear. For the return code it's different, every program has a return code, by convention 0 means no problem, all other value indicates a problem, but it's only when a program terminate, not get killed. You also have a process status, and signal, it can give you the informations you want, but not in the script himself. So for what you want you will need 2 script, one script which launch and observe a second script (with Popen) and check if a specific signal was sent to the 2nd script

edit : this is for linux only and will not works if the parent get killed too, for windows you will need the pywin32 module, it's possible to catch a console closed, I don't know for the right-click => close on task manager but try https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/how-to-catch-kill-events-with-python/

Comment: What about the method @freakish mentioned? does that code need to be put in a separate script too?

Comment: He's wrong. You don't need two processes, that's an unnecessary complication. Simply because you can send a killing signal to the parent (especially in case of SIGHUP). You gain nothing.

Comment: you gain the possibility of check the SIGKILL and SIGSTOP signal

Comment: @LudovicViaud Not on the parent.

Comment: of course not on the observer script, the info is for the observed one

Comment: Which then begs the question: who terminates observer and observed, and can you guarantee the order?

Comment: anyone with sufficient permission can kill both process in any order, you can't guarantee anything, this solution just works if the observed is killed before the observer and only on linux, for windows I didn't found other solution than using pywin32 with something like freakish's code but with the windows specific signal equivalent to terminate, not for kill