# Python: Check if Program is being closed

Tags: python, python-3.x

all.

Is there a way, using Python, to check if the script that is currently running is requested to close? For example, If I press the X-Button (close program button) on the top-right to close it, or end the script in any other way, can the script do some code before it ends? Example:

```
# script goes here...

if Script_To_Be_Closed: # replace this with an actual line of code.
    do_stuff
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997056/python-check-if-force-closed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python check if force closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997056/python-check-if-force-closed)

Comment: Which "X-Button n the top-right"  ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers he is talking about the close button of a typical window no matter on what OS

Comment: @Sofian this was a rethoretical question actually - I wanted the OP to understand that a "window button" is not an attribute of a Python script, but an attribute of a GUI (either created by the Python script itself or part of a system pseudo-terminal window) and that quite a lot of  "python scripts" are merely command line tools (no GUI) executed outside of a pseudo-terminal.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple options you may use, like trapping keyboardinterrupts, but the simplest is atexit, which executes a function whenever a scripts is ended (except of a hard process kill indeed).

```
import atexit

def my_exit_function(some_argument):
    // Your exit code goes here
    print(some_argument)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    atexit.register(my_exit_function, 'some argument', )

    // Your script goes here
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  It only works with normal `sys.exit()` or end of main module.  It does not avoid the need to register a signal handler.

Comment: Not really specified in the question, but atexit is supposed to handle CTRL+C (tested with Python 3.8)

Comment: SIGINT (sent when ctrl-C is pressed) is usually handled by python anyway, so that it results in a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. If this exception is not caught (and the session is non-interactive) then python will exit normally (albeit with an error status).  If you try it with SIGHUP, it will be killed directly by the OS unless you have explicitly installed a handler -- atexit does not do this for you.

Comment: Hmmm... As stated by the atexit python docs, only signals not handled by python will prevent atexit from running (ie SIGKILL via kill -9 or so). SIGINT or SIGHUP are handled by python AFAIK, so atexit should run when these signals are received.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I actually tried it with SIGHUP. Although a process can install handlers for everything except SIGKILL and SIGSTOP, there is no sign that python actually does install a handler for SIGHUP. Indeed if you use `signal.signal` yourself to install a new handler, it will return the existing one, and you will see that (even after atexit.register) the existing handler for SIGHUP still comes back as `Handlers.SIG_DFL` i.e. the OS default for the signal (unlike SIGINT, where it is `default_int_handler`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script to do the job

You can see the script command shown below which calls itself after executing the command to run the python file. once the python file is closed the next line will force the python command to run again. you can also customise the behaviour the way you want.

main.py

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 ./main.py
source ./infiniteRun.sh
```

If you need to stop the job just edit the file and remove the last line `source ./infiniteRun.sh` and save the file.